# Input current too high (IR2110 driver)

Tags: transistors, wireless, mosfet-driver

I have been testing an IR2110 to drive a half-bridge inverter for a wireless power transfer application. When running the simulation, I've noticed that the input current is too high.

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! How high is too high?  Please show waveforms.

Comment: What value did you expect; what value did you get. C3 looks massively too high BTW

Comment: Which "input current?"  You have several voltage sources.

Comment: R1 is small as well, and am I reading this correctly, both PULSE sources are 2.6us width out of 5us period, so there will be at least 100ns total overlap (shoot through) even with ideal delay (2.5 to 2.6us)? Also FYI, D6 and D7 do nothing as R2 and R3 are much smaller than the IR2110's output resistance; to get some difference in rise/fall times, consider 47 ohms or more. (Likely, none is required and the diodes could be omitted.)

Comment: There is a short across diode D10. Remove the ground on L3

Comment: The transformer coupling coefficient of 0.15 seems very low, but perhaps you are using the leakage inductance for energy storage?

Comment: I am pertaining to the input current of V3, which has a an average input current of 15 A; which is too high. I am targeting an input current of around 2 A.